# Installshield Environment Variables

Tags: installshield

I'm fairly new to using InstallShield, and I've ran into an issue, I'm currently creating an installer for an addon product after they accept the license agreement dialog I want InstallShield to check for a specific environment variable, if it exists store it as a string if it doesn't, show a dialog to set a path (then store it and set the variable).

The path is for the installation directory of the main product installer was built by someone else, not the addon they are installing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used VBScript to solve this!

Also there was a problem with environmental variables being user only and not machine.